# White screen of death with PHP-FPM, no error logged

Tags: php, nginx, php5, php-fpm

This is a tale of two different php files.

File 1 source:

```
<?php $null->test();
```

File 1 output:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on a non-object in
>   /wwwroot/sites/example.com/public/fatal.php on line 1

This is also printed to /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log (as defined in my www.conf)

File 2:

```
class A {}

function test(A $obj) {
    echo 'here...';
}

var_dump('started');
$a = new A();
test($a);

var_dump('this is going to error out');
test($null);

var_dump('do we get here?');
```

File 2 output:

> string 'started' (length=7)
>   here...
>   string 'this is going to error out' (length=26)

No error is logged.

Relevant settings from /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:

> catch_workers_output = yesphp_flag[display_errors] = on
>   php_flag[display_startup_errors] = on
>   php_admin_value[error_reporting] = 1
>   php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
>   php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
>   php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = 1
```

A value of 1 means errors of type `E_ERROR` only. Your code generates an `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: Oh wow. Serves me right for copy-pasting that. Changed to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` and we're good! Thank you.